# Three.js Camera and Movement binded to Object

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, physics, game-development

I have used the THREE pointer lock controls as the controls for the object and used the perspective camera aswell but when i added them both to the object only one of them is added and that depends on which one i added first. Also as im a beginner im not familiar on how to move the object which ever direction i moved when i use the WASD keys also rotate on the angle that my camera moves. Only the important peices of code are here.

When i move my object only moves in the North, E, S, W direction which it should, but then when i move my camera it still moves in the direction of when it was spawned in, not changed the angle of direction so if i aimed East and i moved to go forward it would go North.

Also when i move in any direction the object moves back to 0, 0, 0

```js
 function e() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

    var playerGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 40, 10);
    playerGeometry = playerGeometry.toNonIndexed(); // ensure each face has unique vertices

    var playerMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      specular: 0xffffff,
      flatShading: true,
      vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
    });

    window.player = new THREE.Mesh(playerGeometry, playerMaterial);

    console.log(player);

    window.player.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0, 20, 20); 
    
     controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
     window.player.add(controls.getObject());
    scene.add(player);
    objects.push(player);
    }
    
    
  ========================================================================= // Then the animation, these are just snippets not ofc the whole thing
    
    function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (controls.enabled) {
      raycaster.setFromCamera(direction, camera);

      var time = performance.now();
      var delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

      velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
      velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;
      velocity.y -= 3.8 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass

      if (window.player.position) {
      window.player.position.z = Number(keys[87]) - Number(keys[83]);
      window.player.position.x = Number(keys[65]) - Number(keys[68]);
      window.player.position.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions

      if (keys[87] || keys[83])  window.player.position.z -= window.player.position.z * 400.0 * delta;
      if (keys[65] || keys[68])  window.player.position.x -= window.player.position.x * 400.0 * delta;
      if (keys[32]) velocity.y = 200;
      }
      controls.getObject().translateX(velocity.x * delta);
      controls.getObject().translateY(velocity.y * delta);
      controls.getObject().translateZ(velocity.z * delta);

      if (controls.getObject().position.y < 10) {
        velocity.y = 0;
        controls.getObject().position.y = 10;
        canJump = true;
      }

      prevTime = time;

      if (camControls) camControls.update(delta);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you should be able to achieve the desired camera movement by making the following adjustments to your code (ie inside the `if (window.player.position)` block).

The key idea here is that you should update the camera's position by direction vectors that area derived from the camera's direction itself. This ensures the camera moves along the correct path, relative to the camera's current direction:

```
if (window.player.position) {
/* 
  Avoid this logic

  window.player.position.z = Number(keys[87]) - Number(keys[83]);
  window.player.position.x = Number(keys[65]) - Number(keys[68]);
  window.player.position.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in 
  all directions
*/

/* Extract the forward facing vector from your camera. This gives us a vector
   by which when can move forward relative to the camera's current pointing 
   direction */
var forward = new THREE.Vector3()
camera.getWorldDirection (forward)

/* Extract a vector that is pointing to the right of the camera's current 
   direction. This gives us a vector that we can move left/right (strafe) on,
   relative to the camera's current direction */
var right = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(camera.up, forward)

// Normalize the vectors to unit length for ensure predictable camera movement
forward.normalize()
right.normalize()

if (keys[87])  {

  /* Add "velocity" vector to the player's current position, based on
     camera forward direction */
  window.player.position.addScaledVector(forward, 1.0 * delta); 
}

if (keys[83])  {

  /* Add "velocity" vector to the player's current position, based on 
     camera backward direction (ie -1.0) */
  window.player.position.addScaledVector(forward, -1.0 * delta); 
}

if (keys[65]) { 

  /* Add "strafe" vector to the player's current position, based on
     camera right direction */
  window.player.position.addScaledVector(right, 1.0 * delta);
}

if (keys[68]) { 

  /* Add "strafe" vector to the player's current position, based on
     camera left direction (ie -1.0) */
  window.player.position.addScaledVector(right, -1.0 * delta);
}

if (keys[32]) velocity.y = 200;

}

// -- ADD TO ACHIEVE THIRD PERSON CAMERA --

// These vectors store temporary data for out 3rd person camera behaviour
const playerPosition = new THREE.Vector3()
const cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3()

// Get the players position, and cameras position
window.player.getWorldPosition(playerPosition)
camera.getWorldPosition(cameraPosition)

// Calculate a vector that will offset the camera, based on the player's 
// current position. This is based on the current direction vector from
// the camera to the player
const cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(playerPosition, cameraPosition)

// Set the distance between player and third person view. Change 5.0 to something smaller to bring
// camera closer to player
cameraOffset.setLength(5.0) 

// Calculate the camera's new positions
const newCameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(playerPosition, cameraOffset)

// Update the camera's lookat object (player) and position (to achieve
// third person effect)
camera.lookAt(playerPosition)
camera.position.copy(newCameraPosition)
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you this actually works, the thing is when i move l right it goes left and when i move backwards it goes forwards. Also when i move in goes very fast and not like before when it was like a player movement. Could you also help a little with that please.

Comment: Hi, great to hear - please see updates above. Notice that each key 87,83,65,68 is handled separately, with a positive or negative "scale" applied for each case (ie to specify forward or backward, left or right behaviour). Additionally, I've reduced 400.0 to 1.0 for all directions - you can adjust the number 1.0 in `1.0 * delta` to say, `2.0 * delta` to double the speed, etc.

Comment: Thank you this also helped alot, as i'm a beginner and well also not the best with understanding simple maths and physics it was hard for me. Also one more question if i could, the player object, before when it wasnt added it was just the camera with controls and you could move like a proper player but now its added to the player object when you move forward or in any direction you can fly that way and glide wherever. And i wouldn't really know how to fix that, if you could help again that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand - do you want your player to be moved forward & left/right based on camera direction, but have the camera follow being the player like a third-person view?

Comment: Like this example but with a player object moving with a camera above like a 3rd person view yes what you said,

Comment: Hi there, just updated code sample above - does that work for you?

Comment: Sadly no, i can't really explain how its different but its like the camera movement with the mouse is now inverted. My site is at http://51.38.36.156 If you would like to check only need to press play. When i move with the keys it moves the camera direction

Comment: Looks good - I couldn't get into the game though after clicking "Play"? It was just a white screen?

Comment: Sorry the server was offline at that point as i went offline.

Comment: Hi again - I was able to get into the demo for a moment, and then it stopped working again?

Comment: Yes i run this all on a vps and as it's in the development of being made i only run the server when i've made changes and when i'm adding to it, it's not on 24/7 and neither do i know when u would be on. Also could i have a better way to contact you like discord?

Comment: Perhpas we continue this discussion here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178887/three-js-camera-and-movement-binded-to-object

Comment: Sadly "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.
" If u have discord my username is Exper#5931

Comment: I'm #0850 on discord